# Python string slicing unexpected output

Tags: string, slice

I am currently facing a weird issue with string slicing. I cannot understand a part of the code below.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

curString = s[0]
longest = s[0]

for i in range(1, len(s)):
    if s[i] >= curString[-1]:
        curString += s[i]
        if len(curString) > len(longest):
            longest = curString
    else:
        curString = s[i]
print 'Longest substring in alphabetical order is:', longest
```

In particular, the part where `curString[-1]` is. I was trying to determine what is the point of `curString[-1]` in that code.

I made this test:

```
>>> s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
>>> curString = s[0]

>>> curString
'a'

>>> curString[-1]
'a'
```

When defining a new variable with the same string and trying the same [-1] slicing , it returns the first letter of the string, whereas I expected it to return the last (due to the [-1] but it does not. Why is that ?

Comment: Oh, cool :D. I can't seem to reproduce the issue, which python is this and which OS? Maybe there's a known bug we could search for, version specific.

Answer (score 0):

This statment:

```
>>> s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
>>> curString = s[0]
```

will assign the value of `"a"` to `curString`. `s[0]` is just the first element of the string `s`, it is not a range or a slice of the string `s`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is(I think) you are slicing the wrong list

```
>>> s = 'azcbobobegghakl' 

>>> curString = s[0]

>>> print(curString)
a
```

Here curString is equal to "a"

So curString[-1] = "a" since the last character of curString is "a"

If you want the last character of 'azcbobobegghakl' do:

```
>>> curString = s[-1]     # This is "l"

>>> print(curString)
l
```